# dynamic dropdown in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver

This is the code with the help of which i have been trying to automate spicejet from and to  fields, the error i am getting is unable to find element i.e,, `//a[@value='GOI'])[2]`.

can someone please help me?

Also if i keep on trying then it shows the error that the very from field locator is unable to locate, though it worked earlier. can someone please explain this to me?

Lang:java

```
driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT']")).click();    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@text='Amritsar (ATQ)']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@value='GOI'])[2]")).click();
```

Comment: I highly recommend looking at the [syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) guide to reformat your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **xpath** is absolutely fine.You need to induce some `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `elementToBeClickable()`.

```
driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT']"))).click(); 
new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@text='Amritsar (ATQ)']"))).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//a[@value='GOI'])[2]"))).click();
```